# How to XmlDeserialize using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

I'm having trouble deserializing the following XML w/ restsharp

```
<Xid>
   <Id>118</Id>
   <Active>true</Active>
   <Xid>20</Xid>
   <CreatedDate>2011-09-16T18:15:32</CreatedDate>
   <CreatedUserId>1782</CreatedUserId>
   <ModifiedDate>2011-09-16T18:15:32</ModifiedDate>
   <ModifiedUserId>1782</ModifiedUserId>
   <TableName>ProjectRate</TableName>
   <ObjectId>644</ObjectId>
   <SystemGuid>157f2e2d-5e8b-41c7-b932-09c1d75d0ccc</SystemGuid>
</Xid>
```

I can't use a class named 'Xid' with a member named 'Xid' as there is a conflict in C#.  I have tried manually declaring the XmlRoot on the XidClass object, but it doesn't seem to be getting picked up by RestSharp's deserializer.  Is there a way to do this with RestSharp, or am I going to need to write a custome deserializer for this particular chunk of xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the class by hand, befoe you can deserialize the XML:

```
public class Xid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Xid { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The you should be able to deserialize using something like:

```
Xid xid = xml.Deserialize<Xid>(response);
```

(Have a look here: [Testing the Deserialization of RestSharp without proper REST-Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896911/testing-the-deserialization-of-restsharp-without-proper-rest-api))